# Likebox faces not loading properly when user is logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

The Like Box in my website loads fine when you are not logged in Facebook, but if you are,   the last row loads only one face with a big blank space to the right. You can check this by yourself going to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

Any solution? Is this a bug?